# How to loop through a dataframe and create multiple excel charts based on single or multiple columns?

Tags: python, loops, charts

My dataframe contains multiple categories with multiple respective subcategories. I looped my df based on subcategories and created charts for each, but I need to be looping by categories and put the subcategories series within the chart.
ex of my df:

```
Date    Purchased  Fruit_orange Fruit_apple Vegetables  Meats_chicken  Meats_beef
5/11/2015   23          67                                                  4
5/18/2015   87                         53           2            9         10
5/25/2015   96                                      
6/1/2015    45          34      
6/8/2015    88                         11           5            3
6/15/2015   12           2
```

How can I loop through the df and chart a Fruit category containing oranges and apples as series within the chart, then continue to loop and let it recognize vegetables as a single column to chart, then again, chart Meats containing chicken/beef within the chart.

The code I have loops through each column creating one chart for each column separately.

```
for c in range(3,maxcol+1):

    ChartTitle = sheet.cell(row=1, column=c).value
    LeftLegend = sheet.cell(row=3, column=2).value
    RightLegend = sheet.cell(row=3, column=c).value

    LeftAxis = sheet.cell(row=3, column=2).value
    #RightAxis = sheet.cell(row=3, column=c).value



    #date range
    refObj1 = openpyxl.chart.Reference(sheet, min_col=1, min_row=4, max_col=1, max_row=maxrow)  

    #trend kpi column to repeat across charts
    refObj2 = openpyxl.chart.Reference(sheet, min_col=2, min_row=4, max_col=2, max_row=maxrow)  
    seriesObj2 = openpyxl.chart.Series(refObj2, title=LeftLegend)

    #loop thru 2dary data
    refObj3 = openpyxl.chart.Reference(sheet, min_col=c, min_row=4, max_col=c, max_row=maxrow)    
    seriesObj3 = openpyxl.chart.Series(refObj3, title=RightLegend)

    #create chart and add data, titles
    chartObj = openpyxl.chart.LineChart()
    chartObj.title = ChartTitle
    chartObj.append(seriesObj2)
    chartObj.append(seriesObj3)
    chartObj.set_categories(refObj1)
    chartObj.x_axis.title = "Date"
    chartObj.y_axis.title = LeftAxis
    #chartObj.y_axis.title = RightAxis


    sheet.add_chart(chartObj, 'c5')
```

Comment: Do you actually mean an excel chart?  As in, a chart in an excel file?

Comment: Yes I did! I apologize for not specifying

Comment: You should post your current code -- there are several different ways to write excel files from python, and any answers would need to know what method you're using.